# ng-show with regex using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have two images , based on input regex pattern i want to display one image at a time.

My code is

```
<input type="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="Enter Password"/>

<img src="../close.png" ng-show="password != [a-z]"/>
<img src="../right.png" ng-show="password == [a-z]"/>
```

What will be solution for this kind of feature.

Comment: ng-if="Boolean"

Comment: <img src="../close.png" ng-show="password != /[a-z]/.tes(value)"/>

Comment: do you have full code , i mean tes(value)

Comment: put your full code, this is for help not for do your own code

Answer (score 2):

```js
$scope.checkPassword = checkPassword;
function checkPassword(input){
 var onlySmallLetters = /^[a-z]+$/
 return onlySmallLetters.test(input);
}
```

```html
<input type="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="Enter Password"/>
<img src="../close.png" ng-if="checkPassword(password)"/>
<img src="../right.png" ng-if="!checkPassword(password)"/>
```

> checkPassword method will return false if the input contains any characters other than alphabets 
>   so close.png is only shown if the password has only alphabets otherwise right.png is shown

Answer (score 1):

I guess below is what you need.

Ideally input elements should be validated based on pattern and with the pattern result we will show the corresponding message to user.

So instead of checking in `img` tags I would prefer to check the input itself with ng-pattern and based on the validity of input I am showing the corresponding img.

#### See the implementation

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController', MyController);

function MyController($scope) {

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <form name="form">
    <input type="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="Enter Password" ng-pattern="/^[a-z]*$/" name="password" />
    <br>
    <img src="../close.png" ng-show="form.password.$invalid && form.password.$dirty" alt="error"/>
    <img src="../right.png" ng-show="form.password.$valid && form.password.$dirty" alt="success" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
<input type="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="Enter Password"/>
<img src="../close.png" ng-if="password != [a-z]"/>
<img src="../right.png" ng-if="password == [a-z]"/>
```

Difference between `ngShow` and `ngIf` directive is that ngShow will just hide/show the element with the element being present in the DOM. Whereas ngIf removes the element from the DOM if not used.

Comment: No its not working with the pattern. Pattern is any lower case character.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('controller', function($scope) {
 $scope.password;
 $scope.hasLowerCase = function (str) {
  $scope.lowerStr = angular.lowercase(str);
  if($scope.lowerStr == str && str != null && str != '') {
   return true;
  }
  else{
   return false;
  }
 }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="controller">
  <input type="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="Enter Password"/>
  <br>
 <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/pretty-office-2/256/success-icon.png" ng-show="hasLowerCase(password)"/>
   <img src="https://dialectline.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/sign-error-icon.png" ng-show="!hasLowerCase(password)"/>
  
 </div>
```

Comment: this code works but if you  put upper case first then lower case, then this code is not working.

Comment: What do you want to do? When you use lower case latter which is you want, it works. but if you want a upper case latter with a lower case latter it not works for that and your question isn't that.